# Making a const unique_ptr then trying to std::move from it gives the same error as if you were trying to access the copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, smart-pointers, move-semantics

I noticed the error when we try to copy a `unique_ptr` (e.g. assign one unique pointer to another) is

```
Error C2280 std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete attempting to reference a deleted function ptrTest c:\ptrtest\main.cpp 7
```

```cpp
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> a = std::make_unique<int>(2);
    std::unique_ptr<int> b = a;
}
```

That's fine, as `unique_ptr` doesn't have a copy constructor defined. You don't copy from unique pointers to move (transfer ownership of the pointer) between them.

Interestingly (OK maybe not), this code throws the same error. Now I know that it's not valid (I declared the first `unique_ptr` as an immutable object), but the error message implies it is trying to call the copy constructor. Is that correct?

```cpp
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    const std::unique_ptr<int> a = std::make_unique<int>(2);
    std::unique_ptr<int> b = std::move(a);
}
```

Comment: since `a` is const move constructor is not a valid candidate

Comment: This is exactly why `unique_ptr` is superior to `auto_ptr`. :-)  `auto_ptr` would have compiled here, and silently altered a const value.

Comment: @Sopel, apologies, not following what you wrote.

Comment: [My brief explanation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3def8d1aca9dc6d5) which you may already understand. `unique_ptr&&` can't bind to a `const`, but `const unique_ptr&` can.

Comment: moving from an object alters it, but you can't alter `const` objects. Which is why `std::move(a)` is same as 'a'

Comment: @HowardHinnant By what magic can a constant `auto_ptr` be altered?

Comment: @curiousguy:  My mistake.  I was reliving a memory from an earlier `auto_ptr` spec with a mutable `T*` member.  This was corrected prior to C++98.  Thank you for the correction.  I should have checked my comments with code before posting them.  There  are other use cases where `unique_ptr` catches problems at compile time and `auto_ptr` allows them to be run time errors, but this is not one of them.  Mea culpa.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

The only potentially viable candidate for the call during lookup is the copy constructor, as the compiler tries to perform a copy initialisation… which it then finds is impossible because said constructor is deleted. It's a multi-step process.

You could call this a C++ quirk, *maybe*, in that the diagnostic is a bit of an abstraction leak. But it does make sense from a technical standpoint.

Comment: Probably couldn't hurt it to have a `unique_ptr(unique_ptr const&& ) = delete;` constructor.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit. What do you mean by during lookup? Does it attempt to std::move, realise it can't move const std::unique_ptr<int> as there is no move constructor with const std::unique_ptr<int>&& defined. So it then tries to do a copy, then realise there is no copy constructor?

Comment: @Prof: _"Does it attempt to std::move"_ I'm not sure what you mean by this. You can't "attempt to `std::move`"; `std::move` is just a cast to an rvalue. First the compiler looks for a **non-`const`** constructor taking an rvalue reference, but it can't find one so it starts looking for copy constructors instead. It finds one and "wants" to use it, but later finds it has been deleted. _"there is no copy constructor"_ There is a copy constructor, but it has been "deleted". There's a subtle difference there that is the key here.

Comment: it find one it *wants* to use? So that means I existed at some point? You it later finds its been deleted. Has the compiler added and then removed a constructor or was it never there in the first place. Apologies fro my confusion

Comment: @Prof: "Deleted" means something very specific here. It doesn't make the constructor not exist. It just crosses it out so that you can't use it.